# Objective-C Class Prefix for a library APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, conventions

Lets say I'm creating an SDK for a company called "MyCompany" and its a unique company name. All the library classes are prefixed with "MC" only the main API library class "MyCompany.h" is not. Is this appropriate or should I also prefix that class too?

Comment: I think it's fine. The main reason for prefixing is to avoid collisions with referenced classes so unless the name is very generic you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's appropriate.  To make sure, I'd download some popular SDKs, and see what they do.  Like Facebook, and others like that.

Also, note that technically, your class prefixes should be at least 3 characters, unless you're Apple.  Per Apple.  Although, I don't think a lot of people use that guideline.

**Edit:** I edited this because I didn't like my first answer...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the reason third-party developers are advised to use three-character prefixes is to avoid naming conflicts with frameworks Apple may introduce in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`MyCompany.h` does not -- **should not** -- define any linkable symbols.  It should *only* `#import` the rest of your framework's/library's headers.

Thus, there is no conflict because there are no actual unprefixed symbols defined;  there should not be a `MyCompany` class, for example.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, this is my first project in Objective-C environment and I'm interested to know why I should not define any linkable symbols and not use MyCompany.m class that implements the MyCompany.h methods (which calls internal APIs).

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed naming scheme matches what Apple does as well as what many third-party libraries do.

I think that sounds like a reasonable way to name your library.